# How to search defined constants in ruby

Tags: ruby, introspection

How can I show all defined constants with the word `"AjaxDatatablesRails"` in it?

I tried this:

```
::AjaxDatatablesRails::Extensions
# >> NameError: uninitialized constant AjaxDatatablesRails::Extensions
```

Comment: I believe you actually want to `AjaxDatatablesRails.constants false`.

Comment: ^^ Very true - this is quite likely an XY question. Are you *really* trying to find all constants containing "AjaxDatatablesRails", or is it actually the case that you know `AjaxDatatablesRails` exists, and you'd like to see all constants defined within this class/module?

Answer (score 6):

```
Module.constants.grep /AjaxDatatablesRails/
```

[`Module.constants`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-c-constants) returns an array of the names of all constants accessible from the point of call.

[`Enumerable#grep`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) then loops through this array, and filters out the names matching the given pattern.

Comment: While this answer is correct, given the fact that this is `rails` (or at least one can reasonably assume this is `rails`). You might want to expand on this *"all constants accessible from the point of call"*. My suggestion being that `rails` has a tendency to lazy load classes as needed and thus this call may not return a complete list in all cases.

Comment: The question made no mention of, or reference to, `rails` - so I disagree that it would be reasonable to assume this. However, it's a fair point that _due to the nature of ruby_ (not specifically rails), code can be dynamically loaded and therefore the list of "all" constants is context-dependant.

Comment: Hmm okay to each their own. However [`ajax-datatables-rails`](https://github.com/jbox-web/ajax-datatables-rails) is a gem specifically for `rails`